# C# .NET running code from an external file

Tags: c#, .net, external

I'm pretty new with C#, and I was wondering if it would be possible to move parts of code (*from my main Form*) to an external .cs file (*still in the same solution*), with the same level of access to variables and functions from my form1.cs file, as my original form1.cs file.

I'm working with the latest version of the .NET-framework and I have no other references to (external) code.

Here is a simple example of what I'm looking for:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Code1
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        // variables
        text1 = "Hello"
        
        public void ExternalCode()
        {
            this.BackgroundImage = null;
            Btn1.Text = "Click me";
            Lbl1.Text = text1;
        }

        private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExternalCode();
        }
    }
}
```

*This form only has a button named "`Btn1`" and a label named "`Lbl1`" in it.*

I would like the code inside the method `SeparateCode` to be in a separate file, but still with the ability to access the variables and controls from `Form3`, and for `Form3` to still be able to execute the method in the external file (`ExternalCode`).

I thought of making this file a daughter of the `Form3.cs`, but as I said, I'm still pretty new at this so I don't really know how to.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, and the reason you can do that is the `partial` keyword there. So create a separate .cs file, that uses the same namespace, and also has `public partial class Form3` (you don't need to specify that it inherits from `Form`, as that has already been done), and then move your `SeparateCode` method to this new file. The compiler will treat these two files as "the same class" and compile them as though you had all the code in just one file.

Comment: Thanks Lasse! Gonna try that out rn. Helping me a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, because the class has been declared as partial, here:

```
       v-----v
public partial class Form3 : Form
```

This keyword means that the file you grabbed that code from can be one of many, all declaring their own partial content for this class.

So what you can do is add yet another file to your project, and make sure it contributes to this class. To do that you must:

1. Declare the class inside the file as belonging to the same namespace as the original
2. Declare the class inside to *be* the same class as the original

Note that you don't have to mention inheritance, such as the part with `: Form` from your original, as this will still be understood from your original file.

So, if you add a file with this content:

```
namespace Code1                        // <-- this has to be the same
{
    public partial class Form3         // <-- as does this
    {
        public void ExternalCode()
        {
            this.BackgroundImage = null;
            Btn1.Text = "Click me";
            Lbl1.Text = text1;
        }
    }
}
```

then you can remove `ExternalCode` from your original file, and it should still work just fine.

The compiler will treat all of these files as building up the same, one, class, `Form3`.